# How to find result of two table as unique when count of column equal one or two?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, select

I have two table , one name of student and other one have lesson of student , I need to find student with have two or one lesson .

```
table 1 :(students)
id , name , family , birth , mobile

table 2 : (lessons)
id , studentID , name
```

and my code is

```
SELECT t.* FROM students AS t LEFT JOIN lessons AS tr ON t.id = tr.userID WHERE count(tr.*) = 1
```

Comment: you got some advance?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer no , dont work answers :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT students.name, COUNT(studentID) AS CANT FROM students, lessons WHERE students.id = studentID GROUP BY studentID HAVING CANT = 1 OR CANT = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT s.id , s.name , family , birth , mobile FROM student s, lessons l WHERE s.id = l.studentID AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lessons WHERE studentID = student.id) as totalLessons BETWEEN 1 AND 2 GROUP BY s.id
```